# How to disable automatic tab discarding on Chrome Debian?

Tags: google-chrome

This is a Q&A format one.

So, I've gone to `chrome://flags` and searched everywhere for "Automatic Tab Discarding" and found nothing regarding it.

I've done that on Debian 9.3 Desktop, with latest Chrome (v64).

I thought that Chrome removed this flag, but I went to the Chrome Flags on my normal computer (Windows 8.1) and found that the flag is available there.

I don't know what's wrong but the way to disable the tab discarding is below.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `chrome://discards` and you will find all the current open tabs.

Next to the tab you want to stop it from auto-reloading, disable the check-mark of "Auto Discard".